# How to implement this function in a single line in MATLAB (Revised)

Tags: matlab, optimization

Please help me in minimizing this for loop to a single line.

I have a set of dataset which is represented as 4D light field data. The four indices are u, v, s and t. Mathematically, I found a way to transform this 4D light field data to another coordinate system. The new coordinates will be a 3D rotated and translated version of previous system.

The resulting indices of the transformed light field data are ub, vb, sb, tb.
Each of them is depending on variables u,v,s,t.

Sorry for being unclear, let me mention that I am trying to transform a 4D dataset through some sort of matrix. In the code below M is simply a 3D transformation matrix.

```
f=0.1; 
n = 11; 
[u,v,s,t] = ndgrid([1:Size(3)],[1:Size(4)],[1:Size(1)],[1:Size(2)]); 
alpha = M(3,1)*s+M(3,2)*t+M(3,3)*nf; 
beta1 = M(1,1)*u+M(1,2)*v+M(1,4); 
beta2 = M(2,1)*u+M(2,2)*v+M(2,4); 
C = M(3,1)*u+M(3,2)*v+M(3,4); 
D1 = M(1,1)*s+M(1,2)*t+M(1,3)*nf; 
D2 = M(2,1)*s+M(2,2)*t+M(2,3)*nf; 
ub = -D1.*C./alpha+beta1; 
vb = -D2.*C./alpha+beta2; 
sb = nf*D1./alpha; 
tb = nf*D2./alpha; 
for s = 1:Size(1) 
    for t = 1:Size(2) 
        for u = 1:Size(3) 
            for v = 1:Size(4)             
                newLF(sb(u,v,s,t),tb(u,v,s,t),ub(u,v,s,t),vb(u,v,s,t)) = LF2(s,t,u,v); 
            end;
        end; 
    end;
end;
```

Now since ub,vb,sb and tb are depending on u,v,s,t therefore, it is not possible to assign it like newLF = LF2;

Now the question is how to minimize these for loops to a single line.

Comment: Without having numbers to run through your code I can't be sure but, try `sub2ind` on both sets of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinate transformations on images (or 4D datasets in your case) are best handled by inverse coordinate transformation and interpolation of the source data.  That is, you iterate through your destination pixel values, convert those (integer) coordinates to (fractional) source coordinates, then lookup the value from the source data, interpolating between the pixels.

So, your first job is to invert the coordinate transformation.  Then, you simply call `interpn` on the dataset, plus the ndgrid-generated source pixel locations, plus the transformed pixel locations.